# How to offset a marker in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, offset, markers

```
plt.plot([2,5],[0,0], marker='^', markersize= 15, fillstyle='none')
```

[image]

What is the easiest way to make the markers go down just a little so the line touches the top of the triangle?

I'm trying to plot a beam just like the image below but I can't even place the markers right lol
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one but with filled marker, refer to [marker doc](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html):

```
plt.plot([2,5],[0.3,0.3], marker=6, markersize= 15, fillstyle='full')
```

[image]

[image]